# Check promo code validity?

Tags: ios, promotion-code

I came across this service that allowed distributing promo codes in a way that you could keep track of the ones that are still unused. I just can't find it anymore.

If there's a better to check ios promo code validity, please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://www.appannie.com/

?

: )

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to [Redeem-Now.com](http://redeem-now.com/)

If you distribute your promo codes through Redeem Now you can track used/unused codes.